# Tagged To: addresses such as user+tag@myserver.de config

Tags: postfix

Alright, I need to have a PHP script hosted on my server to send emails to 'tagged' email addresses on my own server, e.g. "user+tag@myserver.de". I use my own server as SMTP server as well, PHP uses its `mail()` command. So, my server is both sending and receiving.

For receiving mail sent to tagged addresses on my server, I have configured Postfix' `main.cf` with:

```sh
recipient_delimiter = +
```

In order to send those, `main.cf` also contains:

```sh
recipient_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical_maps
```

These 'canonical maps' consist of one regex line:

```sh
/^(.+)\+.+@(.*)/ ${1}@${2}
```

Now:

(1)

Emails sent to, say, user+tag@myserver.de, by my onsite PHP script or even from Linux shell get rewritten and sent to user@myserver.de, the `+tag` is dropped from the `To:` header, which leaves it as `user@myserver.de` and an additional `X-Original-To: user+tag@myserver.de` header is inserted.

I can understand this behaviour, since I configured it in `recipient_canonical_maps`. Because if I don't, emails with tagged addresses do not arrive anywhere:

```sh
Feb 13 21:00:00 myserver postfix-local[11626]: cannot chdir to mailname dir user+tag: No such file or directory
Feb 13 21:00:00 myserver postfix-local[11626]: Unknown user: user+tag@myserver.de
```

(/var/log/mail.log when having recipient_canonical_maps taken out of main.cf)

(2)

At the same time, emails sent by client software such as Thunderbird, using my servers SMTP at port 25, to tagged addresses like `user+tag@myserver.de` have their `+tag` preserved in the `To:` header,  though they, too, get the aforementioned `X-Original-To:` header added. They are delivered correctly where they belong, i.e. to the mailbox of `user@myserver.de`.

---

My **goal** is to have the behaviour from (2) by means of (1), that is, a PHP script, or shell command, email getting delivered right whilst keeping the tagged `To:` address preserved.

My questions are:

- What and where might I have done wrong?
- Why are (1) and (2) behaving different? Is this a hint where to look further?

Any suggestion appreciated!

Comment: php: `mail ($to, $subject, $body);` - how can this be missing a "To:"? I even tried adding another "To:" header as fourth parameter, result is the same: I got a mail with two "To:" headers, both of them deprived of the "+tag" address tag.

Answer (score 0):

I was put on the right track by a comment from @A.B (which strangely disappeared); he mentioned the difference between the envelope and the "real" `To:` header. Plus Postfix, indeed, makes a difference between remote clients and the local machine when rewriting headers:

> **Canonical address mapping**
>
> Postfix versions 2.2 and later rewrite message headers from remote SMTP clients only if the client matches the local_header_rewrite_clients parameter (...) (see: http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html)

Postfix' `main.cf` has a parameter that controls which headers are rewritten:

```sh
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient, header_recipient
```

That was my config.

My issue was resolved by **removing the `header_recipient`** from this setting. Thus, the tagged `To:` header is preserved, the email gets delivered where it belongs.